# Long time access to windows AD shared folder via C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a program that generates Microsoft Office documents on Windows share (e.g. `\\server\i$`). It used to work fine with server based on Windows 7. Now it has migrated to Windows 2008 Server with Active Directory. So trying to access to share (e.g. `\\server\share`) it "hangs" for a couple of seconds, which is really annoying. Eventually my program does has access to the shared folder.

What the problem could be? Should I change the credentials I launch my program with? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: what are you storing on the share? I've not found using shares 'too' slow in the past. although they are obvs slower than local files

Comment: The process stops on base functions such as File.Exists('\\server\share\myfile.docx'). Anyway, I have *.docx documents which are less than 500 kb in size.

Comment: sounds like its unavoidable, you should run the file save in a background worker process or some other threading structure and display a 'saving' graphic to the user

Comment: When I open Windows Explore I can do any operations with files very fast. It seems to me that I should pass AD users rights to the process or so... Threading does not mean user does not need to wait :(

Comment: perhaps if you post your code? IS it a WPF application? It should run as the current user, so the file operations should run as fast as explorer